# Intersect between two lists not working

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists see below.....result is coming back as empty

```
List<Pay>olist = new List<Pay>();
List<Pay> nlist = new List<Pay>();
Pay oldpay = new Pay()
{
    EventId = 1,
    Number = 123,                        
    Amount = 1
};

olist.Add(oldpay);
Pay newpay = new Pay ()
{
   EventId = 1,
    Number = 123,                        
    Amount = 100
};
nlist.Add(newpay);
var Result = nlist.Intersect(olist);
```

any clue why?

Comment: Assuming Pay equality is EventID, Number, AND Amount, there's nothing common in those two lists and therefore nothing intersects.  In other words, you haven't defined equality here.

Comment: What do you mean haven't defined equality here? only different element is Amount = 100

Comment: There's nothing in the question that states _why_ `oldpay` should equal `newpay`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in your `Pay` class, otherwise `Intersect` doesn't know when 2 instances are considered equal. How could it guess that it is the `EventId` that determines equality? `oldPay` and `newPay` are different instances, so by default they're not considered equal.

You can override the methods in `Pay` like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.EventId;
}

public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if (other is Pay)
        return ((Pay)other).EventId == this.EventId;
    return false;
}
```

Another option is to implement an `IEqualityComparer<Pay>` and pass it as a parameter to `Intersect`:

```
public class PayComparer : IEqualityComparer<Pay>
{
    public bool Equals(Pay x, Pay y)
    {
        if (x == y) // same instance or both null
            return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) // either one is null but not both
            return false;

        return x.EventId == y.EventId;
    }


    public int GetHashCode(Pay pay)
    {
        return pay != null ? pay.EventId : 0;
    }
}

...

var Result = nlist.Intersect(olist, new PayComparer());
```

Comment: or you could write your own comparer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx

Comment: @mydogisbox, yes, I was actually editing my answer to mention this when you commented ;)

Comment: Or you can make the `Pay` type a `struct` to have it done for you, though the default implementation is slow because it uses reflection.

Comment: @Gebb, the default implementation doesn't use reflection, it does a binary comparison of the objects. But anyway, the default equality comparison for structs compare *all* fields, which is probably not the desired behavior here.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, But why does the documentation say so? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7.aspx

Comment: @Gebb, that's weird... the [documentation for Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) says something else: *The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for reference types, and **bitwise equality for value types***. Confusing...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, seems like they can do either depending on circumstances. Here is a comment from the source code of the `ValueType` type: "if there are no GC references in this object we can avoid reflection and do a fast memcmp".

Comment: @Gebb, interesting... so actually both documentation pages are inexact ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Intersect` is probably only adding objects when the same instance of `Pay` is in both `List`. As `oldPay` and `newPay` are instantiated apart they're considered not equal.

`Intersect` uses the `Equals` method to compare objects. If you don't override it it keeps the same behavior of the `Object` class: returning `true` only if both are the same instance of the object.

You should override the `Equals` method in `Pay`.

```
   //in the Pay class
   public override bool Equals(Object o) {
      Pay pay = o as Pay;
      if (pay == null) return false;
      // you haven't said if Number should be included in the comparation
      return EventId == pay.EventId; // && Number == pay.Number; (if applies)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects are reference types. When you create two objects, you have two unique references. The only way they would ever compare equal is if you did:

```
object a = new object();
object b = a;
```

In this case, (a == b) is true. Read up on [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) vs [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) types, and [objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c.aspx)

And to fix your issue, override Equals and GetHashCode, as Thomas Levesque pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you need to provide the appropriate overrides to get `Intersect` to work correctly.  But there is another way if you don't want to bother with overrides and your use case is simple.  This assumes you want to match items on `EventId`, but you can modify this to compare any property.  Note that this approach is likely more expensive than calling `Intersect`, but for small data sets it may not matter.

```
List<Pay> intersectedPays = new List<Pay>();

foreach (Pay o in olist)
{
    var intersectedPay = nlist.Where(n => n.EventId == o.EventId).SingleOrDefault();

    if (intersectedPay != null)
        intersectedPays.Add(intersectedPay);
}

List<Pay> result = intersectedPays;
```